# Definition of Covariance Matrix, to divide by $n$ or not.

Tags: statistics, covariance

In most sources, the covariance of matrix of observations $X \in (n,p)$ is usually defined as

$$cov(X) = \frac{\hat X^T \hat X}{n-1}$$
where $\hat X = X - \mu (X)$.

However, after reading [the definition of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix), it is not divided by the $(n-1)$ term. Why? I'm not talking about bias, since they don't divide by $n$ either.

Comment: Divide by $(n-1)$ (and use sample means) for the **sample** covariance matrix. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Sample_covariance. However, if you *know the population means*, then divide by $n$ and use the population means in the sample covariance matrix calculations instead of the sample means (see this section of Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Unbiasedness).

Comment: What you are mentioning is the sample covariance matrix. Being a random matrix depending on samples, it is not a covariance matrix in a strict sense but rather an estimator of the covariance of the original distribution.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I am not talking about bias, they don't divide by $n$ either. Its just $X^TX$

Comment: @SangchulLee how can the estimator differ by a factor of $n$? Seems very large

Comment: Which definition on Wikipedia are you using? The ones without divisions involve taking an expectation. They are basically "averaging" something, which is essentially what we are doing in the divisions by $n$ or $n-1$.

Comment: On Wiki, it's $(X - E(X) ) (X - E(X))$, but my example above is also using mean centering following by division. @MinusOne-Twelfth

Comment: The Wikipedia definition is not $(X-E(X))(X-E(X))$, but rather the *expected value* of this (with a transpose for the second term), i.e. it is $\color{blue}{E}\left((X-E(X))(X-E(X))^T\right)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ahhhhh, thank you!!!!